# T-SQL Too Many Joins on full table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created a query that runs... actually only takes 9 seconds to run by itself. However... when I try to use it as the main table in a left or right join statement it causes that query to fail (timeout).

I believe it's because I'm hitting the table 14 or so times (500k rows in the table) to compare certain rows. I believe there is a way to consolidate this into 2 full table scans... but I don't know how.

Here is a example of how I'm checking two situations... I do this about 4-5 more times.

Thanks!

```
left join

--SUM THE DURATION OF LUNCHES DURING PTO
(SELECT  o.employee,  convert(date, o.start_time) as createdate,


            SUM(DATEDIFF (
                       minute,
                       CASE WHEN S.START_time  < O.START_time  THEN O.START_time  
                            ELSE S.START_time 
                       END, 
                       CASE WHEN S.STOP_time   > O.STOP_time   THEN O.STOP_time
                            ELSE S.STOP_time  
                       END
                     )) as unplanned_superstate

 FROM table1 O  -- LUNCH CONTAINERS
 JOIN table1 S  -- PTO CONTAINERS
 ON O.Employee = S.Employee
 AND s.START_time <= o.STOP_time
 AND S.STOP_time >= o.START_time  

 WHERE 
 O.code IN ('LUNCH')
 AND S.code  IN  ('CODE1','CODE2','CODE3','CODE4')

 group by o.employee, convert(date, o.start_time)
 ) ul

 on ul.employee = segments.employee and segments.createdate = ul.createdate


left join


--SUM THE DURATION OF LUNCHES DURING SHIFT
   (SELECT  o.employee,  convert(date, o.start_time) as createdate,       
             SUM(DATEDIFF (
                       minute,
                       CASE WHEN S.START_time  < O.START_time  THEN O.START_time  
                            ELSE S.START_time 
                       END, 
                       CASE WHEN S.STOP_time   > O.STOP_time   THEN O.STOP_time
                            ELSE S.STOP_time  
                       END
                     )) shift_superstate

   FROM table1 O  -- LUNCH CONTAINERS
   JOIN table1 S  -- SHIFT CONTAINERS
 ON O.Employee = S.Employee
 AND S.START_time <= O.STOP_time
 AND S.STOP_time >= o.START_time 

WHERE 
  O.code = 'LUNCH'
AND S.code  IN ('SHIFT')

group by o.employee, convert(date, o.start_time)
) ul2

on ul2.employee = segments.employee and segments.createdate = ul2.createdate
```

Comment: What are you trying to capture?  I have a feeling you need a CTE or better still a pivot.

Comment: and part of your query is missing.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I did try using a CTE.. this issue was actually on the query I was trying to join it with... I'm not sure what the issue exactly was but I moved some things around and it runs.. not as fast as I would expect.. I'm 3 months into a year.. I need to report up to 12 months.. I have a feeling I may run into issues as the tables grow. I've found that sql server views can be a little.. odd as well.